# JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion in Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, jackson, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I created an app server using Google Endpoints, it is a backend for an instant messaging app. Every user has a list of friends.

When I create a new friend, I am adding users to each other's friend list using the method below. However, it is giving me following error when I add a friend, because of circular dependency.

I looked at other questions and solutions posted. Most of them are structured differently and they didn't solve my problem.

One answer in this website recommends adding `@JSONIgnore`, but I don't have any field to add that. I tried to put `@JsonManagedReference` but I couldn't figure out where to put `@JSONBackReference`. Other examples on this website, usually have another field that refers to parent, but I don't have it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
Error 500 com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: 
Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.google.common.collect.TransformingRandomAccessList[0]-
&gt;com.net.myapplication.backend.model.User[\"friends\"]-&gt;com.google.common.collect.TransformingRandomAccessList[0]-
&gt;com.net.myapplication.backend.model.User[\"friends\"]-
```

**addFriend method**

```
@ApiMethod(name = "addFriend", httpMethod = "post")
public User addFriend(@Named("regId") String regId, @Named("email") String email) {
    User user = findRecord(regId);
    User friend = findRecordByEmail(email);

    if (user == null){
        log.info("User " + regId + " is not registered.");
    } else{
        if (friend == null){
            log.info("User " + email + " is not registered.");
        } else{
            if (hasFriend(user, friend)){
                log.info("User " + email + " is already a friend.");
            } else {
                user.getFriendsRef().add(Ref.create(friend));
                friend.getFriendsRef().add(Ref.create(user));

                ofy().save().entity(friend).now();
                ofy().save().entity(user).now();

                return friend;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**User model**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @Index
    private String regId;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @Index
    private String email;

    private Language language;

    @Load
    private List<Ref<User>> friends = new ArrayList<>();

    public User() {}

    public User(Long id, String regId, String firstName, String lastName, String email, Language language, List<Ref<User>> friends) {
        this.id = id;
        this.regId = regId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.language = language;
        this.friends = friends;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRegId() {
        return regId;
    }

    public void setRegId(String regId) {
        this.regId = regId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Language getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(Language language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public List<User> getFriends() {
        return Deref.deref(friends);
    }

    @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
    public List<Ref<User>> getFriendsRef(){
        return friends;
    }

    public void setFriends(ArrayList<Ref<User>> friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this question is: "How do I return data structures with cycles through Cloud Endpoints?"

If it serializes data with vanilla Jackson (Jackson 1.x, from the look of that stacktrace), you can't. Jackson 2 has support for JSOG, but that would mean abandoning Cloud Endpoints:

- https://github.com/jsog/jsog
- https://github.com/jsog/jsog-jackson